# Add new row without toolbar. kendo grid

Tags: angularjs, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I need to create a new row in table on button click. With toolbar I can do it with the help of this article [Kendo editing-popup](http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/grid/editing-popup). But I don't want to use toolbar. So I've tried this code:

```
  self.addRow = function () {
            self.grid.addRow();
        };
```

The popup appears only for a moment. Any help is welcome.

Comment: try var grid = $("#GridName").data("kendoGrid");
        grid.addRow();

Comment: my code adds row to the grid, but not in edit mode. And I use angularjs, not jquery

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well. It was simple.

Js:

```
self.addRow = function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    self.grid.addRow();
};
```

Html:

```
 <button class="btn btn-default" ng-click='serviceCompanyList.addRow($event)'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-add'></span> {{ 'report.add' | translate }} </button>
```